# Get programs in dock through terminal

Tags: command-line, dock, ubuntu-dock

How can I get a list of the programs that are in the dock through the terminal in the correct order? I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: See the accepted answer on the linked duplicate. You want the `gsettings` command.